# NSDictionary with duplicated objects checked

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, key-value

I’m looking for a structure as key-object, as `NSDictionary`, but also have its method of counting duplicate objects and define these duplications by keys. I try `NSCountedSet` but this class have no pair `key-object`.
Is there any available type of structure on Foundation like that, or I have to build my own?

**.....updated question in details:**

My structure to looking for duplicated contacts, which could be found on their email, because this is unique, despite of their name, full name maybe different, eg:

```
NSMutableDictionary* listContacts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[listContact setObject:@”john.smith@email.com” forKey:@”john Smith”];
[listContact setObject:@”lara.croft@email.com” forKey:@”lara Croft”];
[listContact setObject:@”john.smith@email.com” forKey:@” Smith John”];
[listContact setObject:@”james.bond@email.com” forKey:@”James bond”];
```

the count method of NSDictionary only count the number of its elements. I know that @”john Smith” and @”Smith John” are one, because his email is the same. But NSDictionary doesn’t have the method to find the duplicate on object: @”john.smith@email.com”. I tried the NSCountedSet as:

```
NSMutableArray* email = @[@”john.smith@email.com”, @”lara.croft@email.com”, @”john.smith@email.com”, @”james.bond@email.com”];
NSCountedSet* duplicateContacts = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:email];
for (NSNumber *num in duplicateContacts)
{
    if ([duplicateContacts countForObject:num]>1)
       {
NSLog(@"duplicated %lu time of %@",[findDuplicate countForObject:num],num);
      }
}
```

It found the duplicated email only, could not have its related name.

If I try the structure of NSDictionary as:

```
NSMutableDictionary* listContacts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[listContact setObject: @”john Smith”  forKey: @”john.smith@email.com”];
[listContact setObject: @”lara Croft”   forKey: @”lara.croft@email.com”];
[listContact setObject: @” Smith John”  forKey: @”john.smith@email.com”];
[listContact setObject: @”James bond”  forKey: @”james.bond@email.com”];
```

NSDictionary will silent remove the duplicated key added, and the result of this NSDictionary only left:

```
Object: @”lara Croft” Key: @”lara.croft@email.com”;
Object: @” Smith John” Key: @”john.smith@email.com”;
Object: @”James bond” Key: @”james.bond@email.com”;
```

The Object: @” john Smith” Key: @”john.smith@email.com” has been remove because of duplicated key: @”john.smith@email.com”

Comment: please give an example of what exactly you want to store in teh data structure and what operations you want to perform!?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about. `NSDictionary` also have method [count](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDictionary/count). Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: I updated my question for your comments, I do not know how to add the code and long reply in my comment.

Comment: What do you want to do with the duplicate entries? Do you not want to simply drop them, as in your last example (key:email, object:name)?

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a dictionary of arrays.  The key would be the email address, and the value would be an array of contacts/names.  The count of each key is simply the count of its value (the number of elements in the array).

You can construct it with the following algorithm:

```
NSArray *contacts = ...;
NSMutableDictionary *keyedEmails = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (Contact *contact in contacts) {
    NSMutableArray *contactsForEmail = keyedEmails[contact.email];
    if (contactsForEmail = nil) {
        contactsForEmail = [NSMutableArray array];
        keyedEmails[contact.email] = contactsForEmail;
    }

    [contactsForEmail addObject:contact];
}
```

You can even get the count for any email with simple syntax:

```
NSUInteger countForEmail = keyedEmails[email].count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be checking for a duplicated email earlier in the process i.e. when this information is being created or added.

This is long winded but I think it best explains how to achieve what you're asking with your current data structure.

```
NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                         @"John Smith",
                         @"Lara Croft",
                         @"Smith John",
                         @"James Bond", nil];

NSMutableArray *emails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                          @"john.smith@email.com",
                          @"lara.croft@email.com",
                          @"john.smith@email.com",
                          @"james.bond@email.com", nil];


NSMutableArray *nestedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:names,emails, nil];

NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *foo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *bar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int count = 0;

for (NSString *string in [nestedArray objectAtIndex:1]) {

    if ([tmp containsObject:string]) {

        //object already exists in our array

        [bar addObject:string];
        [foo addObject:[[nestedArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:count]];
        NSLog(@"Adding key to bar: %@ \n foo: %@",bar,foo);

        // use count to access the name associated with the email [[nestedArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:count];

    }else{

        //add object as it doesnt exist in our array

        [tmp addObject:string];

        NSLog(@"Adding key to foo: %@",tmp);

    }

    count++;
}

NSLog(@"foo: %@ \n bar: %@",foo,bar);
```

I still recommend that you should create an NSObject to optimise your data management.

bar will give you your duplicated keys.

foo will give you your names.

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas, it's a good advice. Although I thought NSDictionary do this checking duplicated and inform as a option argument is better instead of silent removing.

Comment: Don't you want to know every contact of the duplicated emails?